# Return a string from a vector partly matching variable values

Tags: r, regex, string, match

I have a vector of strings:

```
keywords <- c("kw 1", "kw2", "kw3", "kw4", "kw5", "kw6", "kw7", "kw8", 
              "kw 9 kw", "kw10", "kw11", "kw12", "kw13", "kw14", "kw15")
```

And a data frame with an empty column Keyword:

```
df <- data.frame("Description" = c("blabla kw10", "blabla kw15","blabla kw 1", 
                                   "blabla kw13", "blabla kw7", "kw2 bla", "kw8 blabla","bla kw11 bla", 
                                   "blabla kw10","blakw 9 kw", "blablakw4", "blakw 1bla"),
                 "Keyword" = NA)
```

I need to find a way to lookup for a string in *keywords* vector that partly matches the value in *Description* variable and return that matching string from *keywords* vector as a value of *Keywords* column in *df* data frame.

I need this **result**:

```
df <- data.frame("Description" = c("blabla kw10", "blabla kw15","blabla kw 1", 
                                   "blabla kw13", "blabla kw7", "kw2 bla", "kw8 blabla","bla kw11 bla", 
                                   "blabla kw10","blakw 9 kw", "blablakw4", "blakw 1bla"),
                 "Keyword" = c("kw10", "kw15", "kw 1", "kw13", "kw7", "kw2", "kw8", "kw11", "kw10", "kw 9 kw", "kw4", "kw 1"))
```

Could you, please, suggest any solution for this?

*Edited:*

Reproducible example of keywords2 vector and df2 data frame:

```
keywords2 <- c("cartucho", "MOLDE", "FILTRO", "BOMBA", "MOTOR")

df2 <- data.frame("Description" = c("CULATA PARA MOTOR", "BOMBA CENTRIFUGA PARA LIQUIDOS", 
    " CARTUCHO FILTRANTE", "APARATO FILTRO MONITOR", "MOLDES PARA QUESO", 
    "BOMBA PERISTALTICA", "MOLDE CON TAPA Y DESUERADOR", 
    "APARATO FILTRO DE MEMBRANA", "BOMBA DE VACIO"),
              "Keyword" = NA)
```

The expected result:

```
    df2 <- data.frame("Description" = c("CULATA PARA MOTOR", "BOMBA CENTRIFUGA PARA LIQUIDOS", 
" CARTUCHO FILTRANTE", "APARATO FILTRO MONITOR", "MOLDES PARA QUESO", 
"BOMBA PERISTALTICA", "MOLDE CON TAPA Y DESUERADOR", 
"APARATO FILTRO DE MEMBRANA", "BOMBA DE VACIO"),
"Keyword" = c("MOTOR", "BOMBA", "cartucho", "FILTRO", "MOLDE", "BOMBA", "MOLDE", "FILTRO", "BOMBA")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
df$Keyword <- str_extract(df$Description, paste(keywords, collapse='|'))
df$Keyword
#[1] "kw10"    "kw15"    "kw 1"    "kw13"    "kw7"     "kw2"     "kw8"    
#[8] "kw11"    "kw10"    "kw 9 kw" "kw4"     "kw 1"
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset and keywords, convert the 'keywords2' to upper case and then `paste` it together as the `pattern` for `str_extract`

```
str_extract(df2$Description, paste(toupper(keywords2), collapse="|"))
#[1] "MOTOR"    "BOMBA"    "CARTUCHO" "FILTRO"   "MOLDE"    "BOMBA"    "MOLDE"   
#[8] "FILTRO"   "BOMBA"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to do it without using "kw"? In my real data set there are no similar patterns in the strings of keywords vector.

Comment: @MaryiaMaziuk  You need to provide a small reproducible example that mimics your original data as regex matches are based on patterns. If you notice the code, it is based on the 'keywords' provided.  Suppose you want to only remove the 'kw', then `keywords <- gsub("kw", "", keywords)` and use that in the `paste`.  But, it is not clear what your patterns are

Comment: @akrun, apologies if I am disturbing you here, I am too trying to learn R. could you please do let suggest me few things on it? I am reading books and seeing SO posts too here. Will be grateful to you sir.

Comment: @akrun Sorry for that. Just added an example to the question.